# Magento cart - get the bundle parent and children product

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, quote, bundled-product, bundle-product

When looking at the cart from code (for example in the checkout_cart_save_after event), how do I tell which items are part of bundles and which are not?

For example, lets say I have a bundle which is a pack of 4 shirts together with a discount, and those same shirts can also be purchased separately, as simple products.

Now a user added this bundle to cart + 2 of those shirts without any bundle.
If I look at the products in cart, by using something like this:

```
Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
```

I will get a total of 7 items - the bundle product, and 6 shirts.

How can I tell which of the shirts are part of the bundle and which were bought separately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

answering self for future seekers:

```
$item->getParentItemId()
```

source: http://davehiren.blogspot.co.il/2014/02/magento-get-cart-items-how-to-get.html